# Mapped type compiler error when strict is true: Mapped object type implicitly has an 'any' template type

Tags: typescript

I have a mapped type:

```
export type Errors<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?
}
```

`strict` is set to `true` in `tsconfig.json` and I get this error:

```sh
Mapped object type implicitly has an 'any' template type.
```

How can I get rid of this error without setting `strict` to `false` or disabling the error?

Comment: Explicitly provide the template type? https://tsplay.dev/NDP8ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the type, so the default is for the mapped type to implicitly be `any` for all props. But under `noImplictAny` which is part of `strict`, TypeScript will not implicitly assume `any`

The simplest solution is to specify a type. To keep existing behavior you can use `any` but maybe consider a stricter type if possible.

```
export type Errors<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: any
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiUrQM4B4AqAfHALxwDeAUHHANoAKcAlgHZwDWwiEAZnPgF0A-AC44AQxaJKAXyA)